# Swift default value for Objective-C selector parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop

I have the following Objective-C method:

```
-(void)setPaneState:(MHPaneState)state withInitialVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity{
    self.paneState = state;
    [self animatePaneWithInitialVelocity:velocity];
}
```

Currently, in Swift code in the same app, I'm calling this method like this:

```
setPaneState(.closed, withInitialVelocity: .zero)
```

I'd like for the 2nd parameter (`velocity`) to have a default value of `CGPointZero`. I know that Objective-C doesn't support default values at the language level, but Swift does, so I'd like to call this method in Swift like this:

```
setPaneState(.closed)
```

How can I accomplish this short of defining a new method that takes just the one `MHPaneState` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a Swift extension on your Objective-C type and give it a different name?

```
extension MyObjCThing {
    func mySetPaneState(_ state: MHPaneState, withInitialVelocity velocity: CGPoint = .zero) {
        setPaneState(state, withInitialVelocity: velocity)
    }
}
```